# How to do POST request to Grape REST API using params block compatible with Swagger

Tags: ruby, rest, swagger, swagger-ui, grape-api

I am using [grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) to build a REST API, I am having some trouble with `params` options.

This is how I do a POST request:

```
# Curl Request
# curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" 0:9292/v1/articles -d '{"title":"hello","body":"world"}'
# {"error":"article is missing"}
# curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" 0:9292/v1/articles -d '{"article":{title":"hello","body":"world"}}'
# {"error":"article is invalid"}
```

As you can see if I omit `article` it fails `article missing`, If i put `article` and it fails `article invalid`.

This is the code, I am using grape-entity.

```
# Entity
module API
  module Entities
   class Article < Grape::Entity
    expose :title, documentation: { type: 'string', desc: 'Title' }
    expose :body, documentation: { type: 'string', desc: 'Body' }
   end
  end
end


# API
desc "Create an article"
params do
  requires :article, type: API::Entities::Article, documentation: { eg: "aklsdfj" }
end
post '/articles' do
  puts params
  article = Article.create(params(:title, :body))
  represent(article, env)
end


# Add Swagger Docs
add_swagger_documentation mount_path: 'api/doc',
api_version: 'v1',
markdown: GrapeSwagger::Markdown::KramdownAdapter,
hide_documentation_path: true,
base_path: Application.config.base_path,
    models: [API::Entities::Article]
```

Specifically the problem is caused by `params` block, it `requires` an `:article` of type `API:Entities::Article`.

Also note that, I am using `add-swagger-documentation`, and this code
produces correct swagger documentation, so the solution have to be
fully compatible with swagger. What is the correct usage of `params`
block without offending the swagger.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here. I guess you want to change your **post** method in a way that it accepts a JSON like this:

```
{ attribute1: value, attribute2: value }
```

instead of

```
{ article: { attribute1: value, attribute2: value } }
```

In this case, you have to change your **params** block to something like this

```
params do
  requires :attribute1, type: String, documentation: { eg: "aklsdfj" }
  requires :attribute2, type: String, documentation: { eg: "aklsdfj" }
end
```

instead of

```
params do
    requires :article, type: API::Entities::Article, documentation: { eg: "aklsdfj" }
end
```

<del>The **params** block above is expecting a JSON containing an article attribute composed by every attribute defined in the entity API::Entities::Article.</del>

In fact, Grape doesn't accept entity objects as a type for a parameter.

Comment: but that's not swagger friendly, see https://github.com/intridea/grape/issues/827.

Comment: Yep. I agree with you. So far, Grape doesn't accept entity objects as a type for a parameter. You have only two options here. You can use the actual suggested approach or wait a new Grape version. :)